# Desctructuring object with object arrays

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have this kind of and object:

```
obj: {
  child1: [
    { type, checked, text, ... },
    { type, checked, text, ... },
    { type, checked, text, ... },
  ],
  child2: [
    { type, checked, text, ... },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

I need almost the same object, but child elements should have objects consisting only of type and checked values. Need my output to be like below example.

**OUTPUT:**

```
obj: {
  child1: [
    {
      type: "type",
      checked: "checked"
    },
    {
      type: "type",
      checked: "checked"
    },
    {
      type: "type",
      checked: "checked"
    }
  ],
  child2: [
    {
      type: "type",
      checked: "checked"
    }
  ]
}
```

So far everything I've tried doesn't seem to work.

My last failed attempt:

```
    Object.keys(tabs).forEach(key =>
      ({
        updatedState: {
          [key]: (({ documentTypeId, checked }) => ({ documentTypeId, checked }))(tabs[key]),
        },
      }),
    );
```

Comment: What should be the end result (an example)?

Comment: Same object. Only difference that child objects, child1, child2..., Should have only type and checked values.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `map`, not `forEach`. You don't want to mutate the original object, do you? And if you do: there is no assignment in your code anywhere!

Comment: child*N*? That's really begging for an array.

Comment: You're iterating over the keys of `tabs`, but you're not iterating over the `tabs[key]` arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate the [object's keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), with an inner [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to create new objects from the properties you want to keep:

```js
const type = 'type'
const checked = 'checked'
const text = 'text'

const obj = {
  child1: [
    { type, checked, text },
    { type, checked, text },
    { type, checked, text },
  ],
  child2: [
    { type, checked, text },
  ],
}

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, k) => {
  r[k] = obj[k].map(({ type, checked }) => ({ type, checked }))
  
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of reduce (to iterate through the object keys) and map
(for your children arrays)

```js
const obj = {
  child1: [
    { type: 1, checked: true, text: 'aaa'},
    { type: 2, checked: false, text: 'bbb'},
    { type: 3, checked: true, text: 'ccc'}
  ],
  child2: [
    { type: 4, checked: true, text: 'ddd'},
    { type: 5, checked: false, text: 'eee'},
    { type: 6, checked: true, text: 'fff'}
  ]
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => { 
  acc[key] = obj[key].map(child => 
    ({type: child.type, checked: child.checked}));
    
  return acc;
}, {}); 

console.log(result);
```